# Postgres jsonb cast recordset from UNIX to timestamp

Tags: arrays, postgresql, timestamp, sqldatatypes, jsonb

I'm working in a Postgres table that has a `jsonb` column. I've been able to create a recordset to turn the json to rows from the jsonb object. I'm struggling to convert `timestamp` from UNIX to readable timestamp.

This is what the `jsonb` object looks like with `timestamp` stored as UNIX:

```
{
  "signal": [
    {
      "id": "e80",
      "on": true,
      "unit": "sample 1",
      "timestamp": 1521505355
    },
    {
      "id": "97d",
      "on": false,
      "unit": "sample 2",
      "timestamp": 1521654433
    },
    {
      "id": "97d",
      "on": false,
      "unit": "sample 3",
      "timestamp": 1521654433
    }
  ]
}
```

ideally i'd like it to look like this but get an error for the `timestamp`

```
id | on   |  unit    | timestamp
---+------+----------+-------------------------- 
e80|true  | sample 1 | 2018-03-20 00:22:35+00:00
97d|false | sample 2 | 2018-03-21 17:47:13+00:00
97d|false | sample 3 | 2018-03-21 17:47:13+00:00
```

this is what i have so far which returns the expected values for the columns but gives an error for the `timestamp` column

```
select b.*
from device d
cross join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(d.events->'signal') as 
    b("id" integer, "on" boolean, "unit" text, "timestamp" timestamp)
```

the `timestamp` datatype is throwing off an error.

*[22008] ERROR: date/time field value out of range*

Any help or suggestions for casting the `timestamp` from UNIX to an actual timestamp is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify it as `INTEGER` in column definition list and then Convert it to `TIMESTAMP` using `TO_TIMESTAMP`

Furthermore, The`id` which you are trying to define can't be `integer`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18786/18)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT b.id
    ,b.ON
    ,b.unit
    ,to_timestamp("timestamp") AS "timestamp"
FROM device d
CROSS JOIN lateral jsonb_to_recordset(d.events -> 'signal')
AS b("id" TEXT, "on" boolean, "unit" TEXT, "timestamp" INT)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18786/18/0)**:

```
|  id |    on |     unit |            timestamp |
|-----|-------|----------|----------------------|
| e80 |  true | sample 1 | 2018-03-20T00:22:35Z |
| 97d | false | sample 2 | 2018-03-21T17:47:13Z |
| 97d | false | sample 3 | 2018-03-21T17:47:13Z |
```